# Select specific columns from two tables 

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose I have two tables `tblEmployee` and `tblEmpSalary`. I need to write a SQL statement to get a list of all employees, their name and salary, who receive the highest salary in each department.

Sample table data is here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT e.strEmpName, s.monSalary
FROM tblEmployee e
JOIN tblEmpSalary s ON e.intEmployeeID = s.intEmployeeID
WHERE e.strDepartment + '-' + CAST(s.monSalary AS varchar(20)) IN (
     SELECT e2.strDepartment + '-' + CAST(MAX(s2.monSalary) AS varchar(20))
     FROM tblEmployee e2
     JOIN tblEmpSalary s2 ON e2.intEmployeeID = s2.intEmployeeID
     GROUP BY e2.strDepartment)
```

Disclaimer: I can't test this query right now, so it could have some small detail wrong.

Comment: Hi @Pablo it's sound good but through an error like 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'c++-' to data type int'.There is no department id ,here's only department name.

Comment: @yeasir007 OK, I changed the query a bit, I thik that should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use ranking functions in this case:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    e.*,
    s.monSalary,
    rnk = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY e.strDepartment ORDER BY s.monSalary DESC)
  FROM tblEmplopyee e
  INNER JOIN tblEmpSalary s ON e.intEmployeeID = s.intEmployeeID
)
SELECT
  intEmploeeID,
  strEmpName,
  strDepartment,
  monSalary
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk = 1
```

The `RANK()` function will do if you only need those who's got the topmost salary. With `RANK()`, the query may return more than employee per department if they have the same salary.

Alternatively, you can use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `RANK()`, with the same effect, but `DENSE_RANK()` would also allow you to get employees with top *`n`* *salaries*. (You would be able to specify that in the `WHERE` condition like this:

```
WHERE rnk <= n
```

)

If, however, you need *exactly* one employee per department, even if there are several of them matching the requirement, use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()`. But then you'll probably need to add another criterion to the `ORDER BY` clause of the ranking function, e.g. like this:

```
... ORDER BY s.monSalary DESC, e.strEmpName ASC)
```

In fact, `ROW_NUMBER()` would simply make your query employee-oriented rather than salary-oriented. With `ROW_NUMBER()`, you would be able to have your query return top *`n`* most-paid *employees*, using the same condition as with `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
WHERE rnk <= n
```

You can read more about ranking functions in SQL Server on MSDN:

- [Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 I prefer this solution because it is easier to add more fields either for the ranking criteria or the grouping (In this example they may have sub-departments.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   a.d, a.m, b.strEmpName 
FROM     (
          SELECT    strDepartment d, MAX(monSalary) m 
          FROM      (
                     SELECT    * 
                     FROM      tblEmployee e 
                     LEFT JOIN tblEmpSalary s ON e.inEmployeeID = s.intEmployeeID
                    ) 
           GROUP BY strDepartment
          ) a 
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT    * 
           FROM      tblEmployee e 
           LEFT JOIN tblEmpSalary s ON e.inEmployeeID = s.intEmployeeID
          ) b ON a.d=b.strDepartment AND a.m=b.M
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tblEmployee.strEmpName, max_salaries.strDepartment, max_salaries.salary
FROM (SELECT tblEmployee.strDepartment, MAX(monSalary) 
      FROM tblEmployee INNER JOIN tblEmpSalary 
           ON tblEmployee.intEmployeeID = tblEmpSalary.intEmployeeID
      GROUP BY tblEmployee.strDepartment) max_salaries
INNER JOIN tblEmployee ON tblEmployee.strDepartment = max_salaries.strDepartment
INNER JOIN tblEmpSalary ON tblEmpSalary.monSalary = max_salaries.salary
           AND tblEmpSalary.intEmployeeID = tblEmployee.intEmployeeID
```

In case of two or more employees with equal max salaries - this will return all of them for the specified department.